# Multiplication of exponential in the data using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, math

I have an excel file with data in only one column, which i uploaded using the following script:

```
data=pd.read_excel('ftir.xlsx')
```

now I am doing operations on file, using pre-defined variables as follows:

```
data1 = (8*pii*h*c)/(data**5)

data2=  ((h*c)/(data*k*t))

result= data1*(1/(math.exp(data2)-1))
```

Then I am getting the error as following:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not DataFrame
```

Kindly suggest me the solution of this with full description of code.

Comment: Kindly add the output of data.head to your question, please?

Comment: Use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
result= data1*(1/(math.exp(data2)-1))
```

By:

```
import numpy as np

result= data1*(1/(np.exp(data2)-1))
           HERE --^
```

Comment: Glad to read that. Don't forget to accept answer if this fits your need, please :)

Comment: I am following your answer, but how to accept the anser I don't know.

Comment: hehe :-)  thnk you for your guide, I have accepted your answer. :-)